# How to control whether ActiveRecord uses $1, $2.. placeholders when bulding queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, prepared-statement

I have a `User` model that has two attributes `community_id` (integer) and `remote_id` (string).

When I run `User.where(community_id: 1, remote_id: 'abc')`, I see in the logs the following query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."community_id" = $1 AND
  "users"."remote_id" = 'abc' [["community_id", 1]]
```

Why is ActiveRecord using the `$1` placeholder for `community_id`, but does not use `$2` for `remote_id`?

It seems that because it's not using the placeholder, AR will generate a different prepared statement for each value of `remote_id`. This fills up the pool of prepared statements and may result in conflicts.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way to "force" ActiveRecord to use the placeholders, using `find_by_sql` with column bindings:

```
columns = User.connection.schema_cache.columns_hash("users")

User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE community_id = $1 AND remote_id = $2 LIMIT 1",
  [[columns["community_id"], 1], [columns["remote_id"], "abc"]])
```

which results in the following prepared statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE community_id = $1 AND remote_id = $2 LIMIT 1 [["community_id", 1], ["remote_id", "abc"]]
```

Now all queries use the same statement, with different parameters, as it should be.

I don't know if there is a better/more elegant way to get the AR column definitions than from `schema_cache`, but this does the job.